# $k_{n+1}\le (1+2\varepsilon)k_n$ for $k_n:=\lfloor(1+\varepsilon)^n\rfloor$ and $\varepsilon>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Let $$k_n:=\lfloor(1+\varepsilon)^n\rfloor\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\max\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}:k\le(1+\varepsilon)^n\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb{N}$$ How can we prove $k_{n+1}\le (1+2\varepsilon)k_n$?

Of course, from the definition of $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $$k_n\ge\frac{1}{2}(1+\varepsilon)^n$$ we've got $$\frac{k_{n+1}}{k_n}\le\frac{(1+\varepsilon)^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2}(1+\varepsilon)^n}=2+2\varepsilon$$ However, that's a weaker result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n\in \Bbb N$. Set $\delta = \varepsilon(k_n - 1)$. Then $\delta \ge 0$. Hence, by definition of $k_{n+1}$, there exists a $k\in \Bbb N$ with $k \le (1 +\varepsilon)^{n+1}$ such that $k_{n+1} \le k + \delta$. Thus $$k_{n+1} \le (1 + \varepsilon)^{n+1} + \varepsilon(k_n - 1) < (1 + \varepsilon)(k_n + 1) + \varepsilon(k_n - 1) = (1 + 2\varepsilon)k_n + 1.$$ Therefore, $k_{n+1} \le (1 + 2\varepsilon)k_n$.